# Automapper, mapping to a complex object

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have 2 classes i'm trying to map namely

1) Entity
2) DTO

I'm trying to map Entity.Foo to DTO.Child.Foo

Obviously the below will not work, how do I achieve this. I need to create a new instance of Child and then attach that to the Mapper and then set the Foo property but my AutoMapper skills are not that good!

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, DTO>()
 .ForMember("Child.Foo", m => m.MapFrom(entity => entity.Foo))
```

Comment: What's the type of "Entity.Foo"?  What's the type of "DTO.Child"?  What's the type of "DTO.Child.Foo"?

Answer (score 2):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, DTO>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Foo, 
        o => o.ResolveUsing(s => new DTO.Child { Foo = s.Foo }))
```

// comment