# Automapper complex objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I've begun implementing this;
[Automapper, mapping to a complex object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498242/automapper-mapping-to-a-complex-object) but figured there must be a better way.

So I created this;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<StoreTransportWindow, CSVWindow>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DC, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.DC.number))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.Type))
;

Mapper.CreateMap<Store, CSVStore>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StoreName, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StoreNumber, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.number))
;
```

Now I'd like to use the above mappings in the primary map;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Store, CSVLineObject>()
    .ForMember( dest => dest.store, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(/* This is where I'd like to use the above Store to  CSVStore mapping */)) 
;
```

Is this possible?

**edit**

```
public class CSVStore
{
    public string StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
}

public class CSVWindow
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DC { get; set; }
    public string TPC { get; set; }

public class CSVLineObject
{
    public CSVStore store { get; set; }
    public List<CSVWindow> storeWindows { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show what you're trying to map? (ie, what is `CSVLineObject`, and what is the type for `dest.store`). Also note that it looks like you should be using `MapFrom` instead of `ResolveUsing`, and the second property in the first mapping (`dest.Type`) is automatically mapped by convention.

Comment: Whats `Store`? I'm trying to work out why you're mapping `Store` to `CSVLineObject` instead of doing something like `CSVLineObject.store = Mapper.Map<Store, CSVStore>(store)`. I guess if you wanted to you could do something like `Mapper.CreateMap<Store, CSVLineObject>().ForMember(dest => dest.store, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<Store, CSVStore>(src)));`

Comment: Store is simply another object.  It has a number, a name and a collection of StoreTransportWindow.  I think the actual objects are kinda irrelevant.  I'm more after an idea of how I can use a map inside another map

Comment: You might also find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875075/automapper-what-is-the-difference-between-mapfrom-and-resolveusing

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the initial mappings should probably be more like:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<StoreTransportWindow, CSVWindow>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DC, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DC.number));
// Mapping for property Type not required

Mapper.CreateMap<Store, CSVStore>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StoreName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StoreNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.number));
```

Now say you have the following:

```cs
public class Source
{
    public Store Store { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public CSVStore Store { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following mapping will suffice (as you've already defined the nested mapping `Store` to `CSVStore`):

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

However if `Destination` was more like this:

```cs
public class Destination
{
    public CSVStore CSVStore { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'll need to explicitly define the properties to be mapped:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CSVStore, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Store));
```

(Note that the mapping from `Store` to `CVStore` is applied automatically.)

If for some reason you do need to explicitly define a nested mapping, you can do something like this:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.destproperty,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(
                   src => Mapper.Map<SrcType, DestType>(src.srcproperty));
```

I have needed to use that at times, but not very often as the default functionality takes care of it for you automatically.

I can provide more details if required if you can expand on your requirements.

Comment: That last snippet seems to make more sense in the context of the question i think.  What you are essentially doing is creating the map within the map rather than referencing another map previously created right?  Thanks for all your help so far btw.

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned you don't normally need to do that. Its referenced automatically based upon the nested types being mapped.

Comment: This is one situation where I had to explicitly define the mapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334938/automapper-flattening-of-nested-mappings-asks-for-a-custom-resolver